Python module to get PDF text coordinates
Is there a Python module that has the possibility of returning contents of a PDF file as a list of bounding boxes, with top and left coordinates and text value? Something like Firefox has would be ideal, this is what I mean.

So it would be something like this:
[{'left': 72, 'top': 14.18, 'text': 'YesLogic Pty. Ltd'}, {'left': 72, 'top': 15.75, 'text': '7 / 39 Bouverie St'}]

So, to parse the complete file like this, not just some specific area (I know there are options for that).

PyMuPDF has all that, even in a variety of details: by text blocks, lines, words, characters. Plus font names and characteristics, text color, writing direction and more. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

Thank you for your answer! I found something here under Tutorial https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html Is that supposed to be something like text = page.get_text(“html”)?

This is just one example in case you want a HTML version of the page. XHTML and XML are also possible. Else, page.get_text("words") is a list of tuples (x0, y0, x1, y1, "word",...) for each single string (without space) and its rectangular border. And so on with the remaining variants of text extraction. All that can be restricted to areas on the page ("clip") and supplemented by text searching - also restrictable by clips. There certainly also exists plain text output - without any text meta-information.
